# getting stackoverflow error on executing large sql query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am dynamically building an sql query which has large where condition. On executing the sql using `spark.sql(sql)` I am getting below error

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.merge(PredictionContext.java:175)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNConfigSet.add(ATNConfigSet.java:178)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1551)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
```

Any suggestions solving this.

Comment: Unless you share the query, the isssue cannot be debugged. Please share the sql

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: no...as a work around I created multiple queries with smaller where conditions